# What does scala reflection API Type.dealias do?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I have a simple code,

```
case class Person(name: String, age:Int)
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
val t1 = typeOf[Person]
val t2 = t1.dealias
println(t1 == t2)
```

It outputs true, so I want to ask what is Type.dealias used for? When should I use it? Some code example would be helpful

I ask so because when I read spark code, `ScalaReflection`, it almost always use `dealias` before using the type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type aliases look like

```
type Alias = Person
```

It declares a new type `Alias` which is the same as `Person`.

`dealias` resolves these aliases, so that `typeOf[Alias].dealias` will return `typeOf[Person]`. Because `Person` isn't an alias, `typeOf[Person].dealias` does nothing.

Also note:

> [Type Equality can be checked with =:=. It's important to note that == should not be used to compare types for equality-- == can't check for type equality in the presence of type aliases, while =:= can.](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/api/Types.html)

Comment: Thanks @alexey-romanov. But there is compiling error for `typeOf[Alias]`, it complains that there is no TypeTag available for Alias

Comment: What Scala version are you using?

Comment: In the command line, it works for me now, both 2.11.8 and 2.12.2.But it doesn't in my Inteillj Idea..